# How to extract each key-value pair of a decoded base64 column into individual columns

Tags: mysql, sql, base64

I would like to extract each key-value pair of a decoded base64 column.

Key: Column Name

Value: Value under that column

**Example of data:**

```
SELECT from_base64('eyJhIjo2MywiYyI6Mjk4LCJuIjoxLCJzIjoxLCJlIjo0MCwicCI6NH0=') as decode
```

**Data Output:**

```
{"a":63,"c":298,"n":1,"s":1,"e":40,"p":4}
```

**Desired Output**

```
+----+-----+---+-----+
| a  |  c  | n | ... |
+----+-----+---+-----+
| 63 | 298 | 1 | ... |
+----+-----+---+-----+
```

**Version: 5.7.31**

Comment: Dynamic SQL (PREPARE).

Comment: @Akina, I would also appreciate some hints, how we can use `prepare` concept over here?.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: added version to my question @Akina

Comment: What is maximal amount of keys per one JSON? Does the keys list in different JSONs differs, and what is maximal possible distinct key values amount? Is it possible that one JSON contains two equal key values with the same/different values?

Comment: @Akina 6 is the max amount of distinct keys. The keys are always in the same order and never differ

Comment: *The keys are always in the same order and never differ* but some key(s) may absent in a value, is it?

Comment: @Akina No there is always a value for each pair ( and only 1) but sometimes there could be a NULL

Comment: I.e. the list of keys may be hardcoded. This simplify the convertion.

Comment: *sometimes there could be a NULL* Show exact value example(s) with NULL.

Comment: @Akina 'eyJhIjo5MywiYyI6NjU2LCJuIjoxLCJzIjoxLCJlIjo5LCJwIjoxfQ'
whats weird about this, is that I can see the decoded data online but in mysql, it comes out as NULL

Answer (score 1):

The solution: [fiddle with some explanations](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2ff93f3b27864e5d13da6cae893301b9)

Not optimal, even monsruous somewhere. So for studying purposes only!

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE convert_encoded_JSON_to_table ()
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE temp (id INT, 
                       key_value VARCHAR(255),
                       value_value VARCHAR(255));
    INSERT INTO temp (id, key_value, value_value)
    SELECT test.id,
           keys_array.key_value, 
           JSON_EXTRACT(CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(test.val) USING utf8), 
                        CONCAT('$."', keys_array.key_value, '"')) value_value
    FROM test
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(test.val) USING utf8)), 
                                                  CONCAT('$[', numbers.num, ']'))) key_value
                 FROM test
                 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
                              SELECT 1     UNION ALL
                              SELECT 2     UNION ALL
                              SELECT 3     UNION ALL
                              SELECT 4     UNION ALL
                              SELECT 5     UNION ALL
                              SELECT 6     UNION ALL
                              SELECT 7     UNION ALL
                              SELECT 8     UNION ALL
                              SELECT 9     ) numbers
                 HAVING key_value IS NOT NULL ) keys_array
    HAVING value_value IS NOT NULL;
    SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE output(id INT,',
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT key_value, ' VARCHAR(255)'),
                  ');')
    INTO @sql
    FROM temp;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
    INSERT INTO output (id)
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM temp;
    BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE _id INT;
        DECLARE _key, _value VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id, key_value, value_value FROM temp;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        OPEN cur;
        cycle: LOOP
            FETCH FROM cur INTO _id, _key, _value;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE cycle;
            END IF;
            SET @sql := CONCAT('UPDATE output SET `',
                               _key,
                               '`=''',
                               _value,
                               ''' WHERE id=',
                               _id);
            PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DROP PREPARE stmt;
        END LOOP cycle;
        CLOSE cur;
    END;
    SELECT * FROM output;
    DROP TABLE temp;
    DROP TABLE output;
END
```

Recommendation: upgrade MySQL version to 8.0.4 or above.

Answer (score 1):

> Version: 5.7.31
>
> 6 is the max amount of distinct keys.

```sql
INSERT INTO output (id, a, c, n, s, e, p)
SELECT test.id, 
       JSON_EXTRACT(CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(test.val) USING utf8), '$."a"') key_a,
       JSON_EXTRACT(CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(test.val) USING utf8), '$."c"') key_c,
       JSON_EXTRACT(CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(test.val) USING utf8), '$."n"') key_n,
       JSON_EXTRACT(CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(test.val) USING utf8), '$."s"') key_s,
       JSON_EXTRACT(CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(test.val) USING utf8), '$."e"') key_e,
       JSON_EXTRACT(CONVERT(FROM_BASE64(test.val) USING utf8), '$."p"') key_p
FROM test;
SELECT * FROM output;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=955b1e541edc9cc76fe2a8198b6b3139)